# Removing duplicated in mongodb not behaving as expected

Tags: mongodb

I have a table in mongodb that I have realized has duplicated due to a required data parsing update based on underlying source data.

Due to the change in the source, to code was having an unexpected behavior and inserting many duplicates.

The following query should return a single value:

```js
db.opts.find({
  $query: {
    ticker: "VXX",
    date: 20150423,
    callPut: "P",
    Strike: 27,
    maturity: 20150424
  },
  $orderby: {
    maturity: 1
  }
})
```

Yet due to the bug in the code, I have multiple entries for this observation unfortunately. One of the observations looks like this:

```js
{
  "_id": ObjectId("55396c1c44fea47bde858c78"),
  "date": 20150423,
  "ticker": "VXX",
  "callPut": "P",
  "Last": 6.1,
  "Vol": 25,
  "Chg": 0.43,
  "maturity": 20150424,
  "Symbol": "VXX150424P00027000",
  "Open Int": 809,
  "Strike": 27,
  "Ask": 6.1,
  "Bid": 5.85
}
```

Now, my goal is to remove the duplicates that share certain fields.

I tried running the following:

```js
db.opts.ensureIndex({
  date: 1,
  ticker: 1,
  callPut: 1,
  maturity: 1,
  Symbol: 1,
  Strike: 1
}, {
  unique: true,
  dropDups: true
})
```

Yet the duplicates did not drop.

I additionally tried:

```js
db.opts.createIndex({
  date: 1,
  ticker: 1,
  callPut: 1,
  maturity: 1,
  Symbol: 1,
  Strike: 1
}, {
  unique: true,
  dropDups: true
})
```

I do not have indices defined on these fields outside of what is documented above. The collection is quite vanilla as I created it and insert data daily. Nothing else yet.

The duplicate data looks like this:

```js
> db.opts.find({$query:{ticker:"VXX",date:20150423,callPut:"P",Strike:27}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55396c1c44fea47bde858c78"), "date" : 20150423, "ticker" : "V
XX", "callPut" : "P", "Last" : 6.1, "Vol" : 25, "Chg" : 0.43, "maturity" : 20150
424, "Symbol" : "VXX150424P00027000", "Open Int" : 809, "Strike" : 27, "Ask" : 6
.1, "Bid" : 5.85 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55396c1c44fea47bde858cd1"), "date" : 20150423, "ticker" : "V
XX", "callPut" : "P", "Last" : 6.1, "Vol" : 25, "Chg" : 0.43, "maturity" : 20150
424, "Symbol" : "VXX150424P00027000", "Open Int" : 809, "Strike" : 27, "Ask" : 6
.1, "Bid" : 5.85 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55396c1c44fea47bde858d2a"), "date" : 20150423, "ticker" : "V
XX", "callPut" : "P", "Last" : 6.1, "Vol" : 25, "Chg" : 0.43, "maturity" : 20150
424, "Symbol" : "VXX150424P00027000", "Open Int" : 809, "Strike" : 27, "Ask" : 6
.1, "Bid" : 5.85 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55396c1d44fea47bde858d83"), "date" : 20150423, "ticker" : "V
XX", "callPut" : "P", "Last" : 6.1, "Vol" : 25, "Chg" : 0.43, "maturity" : 20150
424, "Symbol" : "VXX150424P00027000", "Open Int" : 809, "Strike" : 27, "Ask" : 6
.1, "Bid" : 5.85 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55396c1d44fea47bde858ddc"), "date" : 20150423, "ticker" : "V
XX", "callPut" : "P", "Last" : 6.1, "Vol" : 25, "Chg" : 0.43, "maturity" : 20150
424, "Symbol" : "VXX150424P00027000", "Open Int" : 809, "Strike" : 27, "Ask" : 6
.1, "Bid" : 5.85 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55396c1d44fea47bde858e35"), "date" : 20150423, "ticker" : "V
XX", "callPut" : "P", "Last" : 6.1, "Vol" : 25, "Chg" : 0.43, "maturity" : 20150
424, "Symbol" : "VXX150424P00027000", "Open Int" : 809, "Strike" : 27, "Ask" : 6
.1, "Bid" : 5.85 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55396c1e44fea47bde858e8e"), "date" : 20150423, "ticker" : "V
XX", "callPut" : "P", "Last" : 6.1, "Vol" : 25, "Chg" : 0.43, "maturity" : 20150
424, "Symbol" : "VXX150424P00027000", "Open Int" : 809, "Strike" : 27, "Ask" : 6
.1, "Bid" : 5.85 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55396c1e44fea47bde858ee7"), "date" : 20150423, "ticker" : "V
XX", "callPut" : "P", "Last" : 6.1, "Vol" : 25, "Chg" : 0.43, "maturity" : 20150
424, "Symbol" : "VXX150424P00027000", "Open Int" : 809, "Strike" : 27, "Ask" : 6
.1, "Bid" : 5.85 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55396c1e44fea47bde858f40"), "date" : 20150423, "ticker" : "V
XX", "callPut" : "P", "Last" : 6.1, "Vol" : 25, "Chg" : 0.43, "maturity" : 20150
424, "Symbol" : "VXX150424P00027000", "Open Int" : 809, "Strike" : 27, "Ask" : 6
.1, "Bid" : 5.85 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55396c1f44fea47bde858f99"), "date" : 20150423, "ticker" : "V
XX", "callPut" : "P", "Last" : 6.1, "Vol" : 25, "Chg" : 0.43, "maturity" : 20150
424, "Symbol" : "VXX150424P00027000", "Open Int" : 809, "Strike" : 27, "Ask" : 6
.1, "Bid" : 5.85 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55396c1f44fea47bde858ff2"), "date" : 20150423, "ticker" : "V
XX", "callPut" : "P", "Last" : 6.1, "Vol" : 25, "Chg" : 0.43, "maturity" : 20150
424, "Symbol" : "VXX150424P00027000", "Open Int" : 809, "Strike" : 27, "Ask" : 6
.1, "Bid" : 5.85 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55396c2044fea47bde85904b"), "date" : 20150423, "ticker" : "V
XX", "callPut" : "P", "Last" : 6.1, "Vol" : 25, "Chg" : 0.43, "maturity" : 20150
424, "Symbol" : "VXX150424P00027000", "Open Int" : 809, "Strike" : 27, "Ask" : 6
.1, "Bid" : 5.85 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55396c2044fea47bde8590a4"), "date" : 20150423, "ticker" : "V
XX", "callPut" : "P", "Last" : 6.1, "Vol" : 25, "Chg" : 0.43, "maturity" : 20150
424, "Symbol" : "VXX150424P00027000", "Open Int" : 809, "Strike" : 27, "Ask" : 6
.1, "Bid" : 5.85 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55396c2044fea47bde8590fd"), "date" : 20150423, "ticker" : "V
XX", "callPut" : "P", "Last" : 6.1, "Vol" : 25, "Chg" : 0.43, "maturity" : 20150
424, "Symbol" : "VXX150424P00027000", "Open Int" : 809, "Strike" : 27, "Ask" : 6
.1, "Bid" : 5.85 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55396c2144fea47bde859156"), "date" : 20150423, "ticker" : "V
XX", "callPut" : "P", "Last" : 6.1, "Vol" : 25, "Chg" : 0.43, "maturity" : 20150
424, "Symbol" : "VXX150424P00027000", "Open Int" : 809, "Strike" : 27, "Ask" : 6
.1, "Bid" : 5.85 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55396c2144fea47bde8591af"), "date" : 20150423, "ticker" : "V
XX", "callPut" : "P", "Last" : 6.1, "Vol" : 25, "Chg" : 0.43, "maturity" : 20150
424, "Symbol" : "VXX150424P00027000", "Open Int" : 809, "Strike" : 27, "Ask" : 6
.1, "Bid" : 5.85 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55396c2244fea47bde859208"), "date" : 20150423, "ticker" : "V
XX", "callPut" : "P", "Last" : 6.1, "Vol" : 25, "Chg" : 0.43, "maturity" : 20150
424, "Symbol" : "VXX150424P00027000", "Open Int" : 809, "Strike" : 27, "Ask" : 6
.1, "Bid" : 5.85 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55396c2244fea47bde859261"), "date" : 20150423, "ticker" : "V
XX", "callPut" : "P", "Last" : 6.1, "Vol" : 25, "Chg" : 0.43, "maturity" : 20150
424, "Symbol" : "VXX150424P00027000", "Open Int" : 809, "Strike" : 27, "Ask" : 6
.1, "Bid" : 5.85 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55396c2244fea47bde8592ba"), "date" : 20150423, "ticker" : "V
XX", "callPut" : "P", "Last" : 6.1, "Vol" : 25, "Chg" : 0.43, "maturity" : 20150
424, "Symbol" : "VXX150424P00027000", "Open Int" : 809, "Strike" : 27, "Ask" : 6
.1, "Bid" : 5.85 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55396c2344fea47bde859313"), "date" : 20150423, "ticker" : "V
XX", "callPut" : "P", "Last" : 6.1, "Vol" : 25, "Chg" : 0.43, "maturity" : 20150
424, "Symbol" : "VXX150424P00027000", "Open Int" : 809, "Strike" : 27, "Ask" : 6
.1, "Bid" : 5.85 }
Type "it" for more
>
```

How do I remove these duplicates?

Comment: first impresion your solution looks good to me, would you mind droping here some duplicated documents ?

Comment: Your compound index has the field `Symbol` yet in your find query criteria there's no `Symbol` field? Try dropping the index and recreate it, this time minus the `Symbol` field `db.opts.createIndex({date:1,ticker:1,callPut:1,maturity:1,Strike:1},{unique:true,dropDups:true})`

Comment: @chridam the index is a concatenation of the fields mentioned

Comment: But you are saying the query with criteria `{ticker:"VXX",date:20150423,callPut:"P",Strike:27,maturity:20150424}` returns duplicates, I'm failing to see the `Symbol` field in that combination. Have you by any chance tried my suggestion?

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using? The `dropDups` option is no longer available in 3.0.

Comment: @JohnnyHK what is one to use then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dropDups` option is no longer available in 3.0, but you can do this pretty easily in the shell with a little script that iterates over the whole collection and removes docs that duplicate ones that have the same key values:

```js
var keys = {};
db.opts.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    // Create a key that concatenates the keys that together must be unique.
    var key = ''.concat(doc.date, doc.ticker, doc.callPut, doc.maturity,
                        doc.Symbol, doc.Strike);
    if (keys[key]) {
        // A doc with this key has already been seen, so remove this doc.
        db.opts.remove({_id: doc._id});
    } else {
        keys[key] = true;
    }
});
```

Obviously, make a backup before doing this in case it doesn't work exactly as you're expecting.